# Code sign errors while developing for iPhone under friend's profile

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning, provisioning-profile

I have my developer information and keys and such set up on my computer for my development profile.

I am developing an app under a friend's profile and I keep getting this error:

> `Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer: ***** ******* (**********)' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain`

I look into keychain and I see two certs named:

- `iPhone Developer: ***** *******` and
- `iPhone Developer: *****`.

However, I do not see any keys set up under this person's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need a matching private key to use your friend's profile. Have him export it to you following these steps

1. To export your private key and certificate for safe-keeping, open up the Keychain Access Application and select the “Keys” category.
2. Highlight the private key associated with your iOS Distribution Certificate and select “Export Items” from the ‘File’ menu. Save your key in the Personal Information Exchange (.p12) file format.**
3. You will be prompted to create a password which will be used when you attempt to import this key on another computer.
4. You can now transfer this .p12 file between systems. Double-click on the .p12 to install on a system. You will be prompted for the password you first entered above**

Once you have that private key imported into keychain the issue should be resolved

Comment: My friend doesn't have this on his computer. I DID find the keys, but they aren't under the certificate like mine are. Also, if it helps the certificate is under CERTIFICATES, but not MY CERTIFICATES.